# Problem with giving properties to the index of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop, properties

I believe that I have a simple problem on my hands, yet I cant figure out what is worng with this code. I want to give a property to a javascript array, yet for some reason:

```
board = [[0], [0], [0]];
    for(var x = 0; x < board.length; x++) {
        for(var y = 0; y < board[x].length; y++) {
            grid[x][y].f = 0;
        }   
    }

document.write(board[0][0].f);
```

I get undefined as a result of this.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you use the variable name `board` in your array declaration declaration, but both the variable names `grid` and `board` in your code.  I will assume that you meant for those two to be the same name `grid`.

In your example, `grid[x][y]` would be the contents of the inner array which is a number 0.  A number is not an object and doesn't take arbitrary properties like you're trying to assign it in the for loop with `grid[x][y].f = 0` which is essentially trying to say `0.f = 0;`.

To get help on how this should work, please desribe what you're actually trying to accomplish because you data structure doesn't match your code and we can't know which you need to change until we know what you're actually trying to do.